# Three independent events

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be independent events and let $P(A),P(B) \in (0,1)$. 
Let $C$ be the event $A \cup B \setminus A \cap B$.
Prove that if $A,C$ are independent and $B,C$ are independent then $P(A)=P(B)$.

We have that 
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) \\ P(A \cap C) = P(A)P(C) \\ P(B \cap C) = P(B)P(C)$$

and I suppose that $$P(C) = P((A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)) = P(A \cap B^c) + P(A^c \cap B)=P(A)P(B^c) + P(A^c)P(B)$$

but I have no idea how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

From $P(A)=P(AB)+P(AB^c)$ and $P(B)=P(AB)+P(A^cB)$ on subtraction,
$$P(A)-P(B)=P(AB^c)-P(AB^c).\tag{1}$$
Since $C=AB^c \cup A^cB$ we have $P(AC)=P(AB^c)=P(A)P(C)$ (last by independence), and similarly $P(BC)=P(A^cB)=P(B)P(C).$ Subtracting these, and using (1),
$$(P(A)-P(B))P(C)=P(A)-P(B).$$
Rearranging this gives
$$(P(A)-P(B))[1-P(C)].$$
If now $P(C)<1$ we have $P(A)=P(B)$ as desired. But $P(C)=1$ leads to $P(A)=P(B)=1$ easily.

**ADDED:** Actually $P(C)=1$ does not lead to $P(A)=P(B).$

Since $P(C)=P(AB^c)+P(A^cB)=1$ we have $P(A\cap B)=0$ (and also $P( (A \cup B)^c)=0$). Then $P(A)=P(AB^c)$ and $P(B)=P(A^cB)$, each since the intersection $AB$ has probability $0$. Thus $1=P(C)=P(A)+P(B)$ and $P(AB)=0=P(A)P(B)$, so that either $P(A)=0,P(B)=1$ or else $P(A)=1,P(B)=0.$ This contradicts the assumption at the beginning that the probabilities of $A,B$ are in the *open* interval $(0,1).$

Comment: Could you tell me why $P(C)=1$ leads to $P(A)=P(B)=1$ ?

Comment: @user2213654 I've fixed the ending now. The case of $P(C)=1$ doesn't lead to $P(A)=P(B)=1$ but does lead to a contradiction to your assumption that probabilities are strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: In first line you wrote that $P(A \cap B) = 0$. Could you me tell why? I didn't understand it.

Comment: Well $1=P(AB^c)+P(A^cB)$ and so the complement of $[AB^c \cup A^cB]$ has probability zero. Since $AB=A \cap B$ is contained in that complement, we also have $P(AB)=0$. [Note I'm using here and in above answer the notation $AB=A \cap B$]

Comment: Ok, now I understood. But I have one question more. Is it any algorithm how solve similar tasks? I have always a lot of problem with similar tasks because I don't have any idea how begin solving and I'm so confused when I see similar tasks.

Comment: @user2213654 The best way I've found is by using Venn diagrams. You can place veriable names in the regions, and try to express the problem assumptions as equations or inequalities on the varibles. Of course if some intersection is empty that region is labeled by a $0$. This way you can sometimes see what's going on better.